# Hammer candlestick patterns - is it valid? Does it work?

Tags: quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, forex

I am beginning some research into the validity of the hammer candlestick pattern and it's use in a trading algorithm.

To compliment this I am looking for others opinions on candlestick patterns:
Is it a valid pattern to trade off, if not why, why?

I understand what a hammer can represent in terms of human psychology, and it seems logical. However from reading there's a general theme of

> *"What looks good, doesn't generally work in the long-term"*

therefore discussion around this would be useful.

Comment: This question is offtopic. Has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a forum for open discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### <sup>"Does it work?"</sup> Let's be Quantitative from the very beginning, right?

---

@cardycakes, after being member of StackOverflow for some four+ years already, you shall have experienced in person the Community practice to encourage **MCVE**-related questions. This will most probably hurt you here, before we will ever move closer to the solution. You might prefer to edit and update your original post, so as to get closer to this S/O standard practice, posting what you have tried so far and what results you face, to discuss the merit, instead of just talking opinions.

---

May want to use the **TruStrategy {SDAAT}** methodology, working in **5D** in order to isolate the principal components for your quant-models:

---

**`Step 0:`** Define the rules:

**S**ELECT POLICY: specify the trading instrument your quant-model will work with
**D**ETECT POLICY: state the Hammer-formation details - all that provides a signal to enter a Trade
**A**CT POLICY: state the exact type(s) of Trade(s), you plan to enter, once Detect provided a signal
**A**LLOCATE POLICY: state the Trade position sizing and Trade Management rules to be used
**T**ERMINATE POLICY: state the exact rules for a Trade termination

---

**`Step 1:`** develop your Hammer-detector, parsing the historical data ( as per Select Policy stated ) and produce the event envelopes' data ( to run the Act & Terminate Policies against )

---

**`Step 2:`** given your preferred Allocate Policy, validate all Act Policies you may find interesting to work with, to generate quantitatively supported, representative data about achievable quant-model performance of your SDAAT-TruStrategy for the selected instrument / timeframe / preferred trading-style

---

### Next, <sub>"Does it work, indeed?"</sub>

**the answer** to both all your questions and all your why yes & why not-s is close to the merit-focused, evidence-based, quantitatively supported, repeatable and verifiable and **becomes MCVE-related.
`Q.E.D.`**

> Discussing hypotheses is not the primary StackOverflow objective

Comment: To confirm I have been very inactive on StackOverflow despite the year I've had this account. However, you answer was extremely informative and I can take a lot from it. So thank you. I bet others will find this useful too.

Comment: Indeed glad you feel it helps you. **Always welcome** @cardycakes